# What is meant by "cock a snook" . How to use it in sentence

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-usage

When I was reading an article I came across a phrase "cock a snook". After browsing I did not find any convincing or clear meaning of this sentence. I also what to use this word in a sentence.

Comment: [How far did you look?](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/cock-a-snook.html)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I mentioned I did not find a convincing or clear meaning of this phrase.

Comment: The link above is the second given (at least where I am) in a Google search for "cock a snook".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What about the example sentences given, they don't seem to be convincing

Comment: The [fifth Google hit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16687/what-is-the-etymology-and-literal-meaning-of-cock-a-snoot-snook) is an even more compelling reason for not posting your question. kiamlaluno's example shows a modern usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth May be for the meaning of the phrase. But my question was related to purpose and meaningful usage of the phrase in a sentence.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is a duplicate of [What is the etymology and literal meaning of 'Cock a snoot/snook'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16687/what-is-the-etymology-and-literal-meaning-of-cock-a-snoot-snook), where a typical example of its use is also given.

Comment: It's probably used metaphorically more often than literally these days: [here's an example](http://www.epp-cd.eu/pedro-agramunt-the-referendum-in-crimea-basically-cocked-a-snook-at-democrats-around-the-world/)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is neither an off-topic question as this [site](http://english.stackexchange.com/about) is a Q&A site nor a duplicate question as in the other question there was no mention of its usage.

Comment: @Rupe I got it from the link

Comment: I quote from meta: '... the implicit [site] guidelines. When a question gets closed, a banner says "There's already an answer to this question.",  which is different from saying "There's already a question asking the same thing as this question." –  jlovegren'. kiamlaluno gives an answer in the previous thread about the 'clear meanings' (literal and metaphorical) of 'cock a snoot' 'The NOAD [states] the phrase (chiefly British) means ... "openly show contempt or a lack of respect for someone or something." ', and also a modern example:

'He spent a lifetime cocking a snook at the art world.'.

Comment: @Rudra The fact that this is a Q&A site does not make the question on-topic. Your question asks for the meaning of the phrase—that is given in every dictionary, phrase finder, and even another question on this very site. That makes this question ***off-topic***. I don’t see how, when you even have a picture of what the gesture looks like, you can be unsure of how to use the phrase in a sentence. If that is indeed the main part of your question, it is a question for [ell.se], not here.

Comment: @Janus: Asking what the expression *means* today is probably Off Topic General Reference, but we do have a question asking about the *origin*, as Edwin says. So my closevote is as a duplicate of that.

Comment: [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/about) as the site says and how can I post this question in [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/about). First of all though the other question was only for its meaning. I made a clear attempt for its usage in sentences expecting for a precise answer which is why I tagged the question for phrase usage as well. Though I saw the answer for the other question my idea was only to get more details on its origin, purpose of using it and usage in a sentence in different context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general understanding of what's meant by '[cock a snook](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/cock-a-snook.html)' **is the spread hand with thumb on the nose**, preferably with crossed eyes, waggling fingers and any other annoying gesticulation that comes to mind at the time. It's what the Americans call 'the five-fingered salute.'

It is  a gesture that generally indicates that you are making fun of something or someone.
Ex : The sarcastic speech of the Minister was like cocking a snook at his political opponents.

Comment: This is so obviously general reference that an answer is not appropriate.